# Как в языке java передать данные из массива ArrayTrip в метод maxValue

Tags: java

```
blic  class InitArray {

    public double[] ArrayTrip()  {
        Time time = new Time();
        double[] ArrayTrip = new double[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            try {
                ArrayTrip[i] = time.calcTime();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        return ArrayTrip;

}


    public void output() throws IOException {
        System.out.print("Время поездки в минутах ");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ArrayTrip()));
    }

    public void sort() throws IOException {
        Arrays.sort(ArrayTrip());
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ArrayTrip()));

    }
    public double maxValue(){
        double max =0;
        for(int i=0;i>arrays.length;i++){
            if(max>arrays[i]){
                max=arrays[i];

            }
            System.out.println(max);

        } 
    }    
}
```

Comment: `public double maxValue( double[] arrayTrip){}`

Answer (score 1):

В параметры метода maxValue() нужно добавить массив, всё остальное для его обработки в нем уже есть:

```
public double maxValue(double[] arrays){
        double max =0;
        for(int i=0;i>arrays.length;i++){
            if(max>arrays[i]){
                max=arrays[i];

            }
            System.out.println(max);

        } 
    }
```

И далее он может быть довольно просто вызван:

```
maxValue(arrayTrip())
```

И еще, название метода arrayTrip() все-таки лучше писать с маленькой буквы.